# Is it possible to write a program that takes a natural number n as input, and finds the shortest arithmetic formula which computes n?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computability

Is it possible to write a program that takes a natural number $n$ as input, and finds the shortest
arithmetic formula which computes $n$? 
A formula is a sequence consisting of digits, $+$, $\times$, ^ operator that raises to a power, and parentheses.
The length of formula is the number of characters in the formula.
Each digit, operator, or parentheses is counted as 1 character.
How to approach this problem? 
I knew that it is always possible to construct an arithmetic formula since each natural number $n$ can be treated as a sequence of digits.
However, is it possible that we can enumerate the set of all possible arithmetic formulas and find out the minimum length formula for each natural number $n$?

Comment: For sure the problem is possible. As you said, you know a finite bound for each $n$. So trying to enumerate all formulas and see there outputs will solve the problem as the number of such formulas is finite for each $n$.

Comment: For the record, while it is obvious that a formula of shortest length must exist, it is unclear to me why there should be *the* shortest formula.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA No, because "9^9" is much shorter than "387420489".

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity "It can be proven that the Kolmogorov complexity is not computable".

Comment: @Gae.S. What mathcounterexamples.net said. Of course, brute-force of all (syntactically valid) formulae soon becomes impractical, but it's possible in principle because for a given $n$ we only have to search for formulae with length $<\log(n)$, where the base of the logarithm equals the base of the used number system.

Comment: @PM2Ring I agree with what mathcountexamples.net said. My point is that for all we know there might be more than one formula of least length, and therefore: "while it is obvious that a formula of shortest length must exist, it is unclear to me why there should be *the* shortest formula". For an example, which may or may not be semantically valid here, $128=2^{\wedge}7$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Ah, ok. Yes, there certainly can be multiple formulae with the minimum length. :)

Comment: FWIW, I think this problem is probably not too hard to solve, because it doesn't have operations like subtraction or division that reduce the size of a number.

Comment: What about computing $2$? It can be $1+1$, or $(1+1)\times1$, or $2\times 1$, or $2\times 1\times 1\dots$. While the "times 1" examples will obviously be bigger than the ones without this, it would seen that given any finite collection of formulae, there will always be a new formulae not in the collection which computes the same number. So it would seem that we can't brute force them all.

Comment: @user400188 You can enumerate all the strings in the language $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,+,\times , {}^{\wedge}, (, )\}^*$ by giving them the well-ordering $a\le b$ if and only if either $a$ is strictly shorter than $b$, or $a=b$, or $a$ is as long as $b$ and $b$ comes after-or-the-same-as $a$ lexicographically. Then you can test each one if it is a string which can be interpreted as arithmetic operations, and if it gives you the right number. The first one you find will be a string of least length giving you the desired number.

Comment: Also if you continue once you've found one up until the first string of longer length, you'll find all the strings of minimal length.

Comment: @Gae.S. It might be a good idea to write that out as the answer. It goes into enough detail to be one I think, and thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @user400188 I don't think I should, because even if I don't think it adds much to the discussion, that is the end of my analysis on the matter.